# How to call ngFor each time, when the variable over which it runs is set multiple times, without using timers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, timer, observable

Suppose if I have ngFor run over a variable - 'elements', to render child component -

**parent.html** ->

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of elements">
  <child-component [data]="elem"></child-component>
</div>
```

**parent.ts** ->
Now parent file has an input setter inside which I set 'elements'

```
@Input("parent-data") public set parentData(value){
     if(value){
         if(elements){
             this.elements = undefined;
             this.elements = cloneDeep(value);   
         }else{
             this.elements = value;
         }
     }
}
```

Here, for first time, when I start with parent component, then '*this.elements*' is undefined, but when I call 'parent-data' input setter next time, then '*this.elements*' is defined.
So, I'm undefining '*this.elements*', then assigning the new value.

I want the div with *ngFor to render **new instances** of child component, but it only **overwrites** the previous existing child components. Hence for this reason, I did

```
....
this.elements = undefined;
....
```

first.
But still it only overwrites old instances of child-component inside *ngFor. What I want is *ngFor to read undefined, then cancel all child-components, then read new value of '*this.elements*', and render new instances of child-comp.
Now this behaviour is possible with help of observable timer, like below

```
@Input("parent-data") public set parentData(value){
         if(value){
             if(elements){
                 this.elements = undefined;
                 timer(10).pipe().subscribe(result => {
                         this.elements = cloneDeep(value);
                 });
             }else{
                 this.elements = value;
             }
         }
    }
```

Here, it undefines '*this.elements*', renders div with no child-comp, then after 10ms, it renders child-comp with new value assigned to 'elements'. It means, here we get 10ms to run *ngFor with elements as undefined, and remove old-instances of child-component. However, I'm looking to have similar behavior with no timers.
Please help me for a non-timer solution.